# Finding normalization of the ring $\Bbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^5 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Determine the normalization of $R=\Bbb{C}[x,y]/\langle y^2-x^5 \rangle$ (denoted $R^\nu$) when $R^\nu\subseteq\operatorname{Frac}(R)$.

($\bar x$ means the class of $x$ under the equivalence relation of the quotient)

This is my attempt - one can check that $t=\frac{\bar y}{\bar x^2}\in R^\nu$, because it satisfies $f(t)=t^2-\bar x$ where $f(t)\in R[x]$.
So, $\Bbb{C}[t]\subseteq R^\nu$. Now, $t^2=\bar x$, and $t^5=t^4t=\bar x^2\frac{\bar y}{\bar x^2}=\bar y$. Therefore $R\subseteq \Bbb{C}[t]\subseteq R^\nu\subseteq\operatorname{Frac}(R)$. On the other hand, taking integral closures of every ring in the chain of inclusions, one then gets: $R^\nu\subseteq \Bbb{C}[t]^\nu\subseteq R^{\nu^\nu}=R^\nu$, which means $\Bbb{C}[t]^\nu=R^\nu$. $\Bbb{C}[t] $ is a UFD and therefore $\Bbb{C}[t]^\nu=\Bbb{C}[t]=R^\nu$

Is this proof correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Your proof is crisp, elegant and absolutely correct. Bravo ! (and +1, of course). It corresponds to the geometric fact that $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb C=\operatorname {Spec}\mathbb C[t]$ is the normalization of the curve $\operatorname {Spec} R$

Comment: The only remark I have is that you may want to show explicitly that $\mathbb C[\overline y / \overline x^2]$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring. In other words, that no funny relations magically appear. This is not hard, as you already know that $\mathbb C[\overline y / \overline x^2]$ is a domain, but I think it's worth a quick thoight.

Comment: Isnt $x \rightarrow t$ the obvious isomorphism?

Comment: @GBA Yeah, my comment is a bit pedantic, but my point was that it's worth thinking about why that's injective. One easy proof comes from the fact that $\mathbb C[t]$ is a domain and that $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed.